# Как обработать ошибку ввода неверной команды на фреймворке для создания telegram ботов на Rust - teloxide

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, rust, обработка-ошибок

В документации teloxide есть пример бота с 3 командами:

```
use teloxide::{prelude::*, utils::command::BotCommands};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    pretty_env_logger::init();
    log::info!("Starting command bot...");

    let bot = Bot::from_env();

    Command::repl(bot, answer).await;
}

#[derive(BotCommands, Clone)]
#[command(rename_rule = "lowercase", description = "These commands are supported:")]
enum Command {
    #[command(description = "display this text.")]
    Help,
    #[command(description = "handle a username.")]
    Username(String),
    #[command(description = "handle a username and an age.", parse_with = "split")]
    UsernameAndAge { username: String, age: u8 },
}

async fn answer(bot: Bot, msg: Message, cmd: Command) -> ResponseResult<()> {
    match cmd {
        Command::Help => bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, Command::descriptions().to_string()).await?,
        Command::Username(username) => {
            bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, format!("Your username is @{username}.")).await?
        }
        Command::UsernameAndAge { username, age } => {
            bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, format!("Your username is @{username} and age is {age}."))
                .await?
        }
    };

    Ok(())
}
```

Как на этом примере можно обработать введенную пользователем неверную команду или например при вводе команды /usernameandage большее количество параметров чем только `username` и `age`

Если эти ошибки никак не обработать, то как еще можно оформить команды в teloxide?